# How to get latest reviews using Google places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have using Google places API for extracting reviews for places.
The google places API providing top 5 most relevant reviews only,
But I Need Latest reviews for a place.

Is possible to get latest five reviews instead of most relevant reviews from google places API?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Google Places API doesn't have an option to order reviews in the response. The feature request for the ordering was submitted in Google issue tracker in 2012:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821903

Unfortunately, it looks like Google didn't set priority on this task. I can suggest starring the feature request in issue tracker to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a paid API for businesses to use to get this info. I have not used it but it is talked about in the issue tracker thread mentioned by xomena (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821903)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, here is an example of using sorting by the newest

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=SOME_PLACE_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY&reviews_sort=newest
```